# Filter and groupby VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data which looks like:

```
date          Product    Result
31-12-2017    abc 1234 
21-01-2018    def 1234
31-12-2017    abc 5678
21-01-2018    xyz 5678
```

I want to filter each date and count the number of appearances of the first string in `Product` , eg: for `date`  `31-12-2017` , the string `abc` repeats twice . My expected output would put a column stating if the appearances are single or multiple. Example below:

```
date          Product    Result
31-12-2017    abc 1234   Multiple
21-01-2018    def 1234   Single
31-12-2017    abc 5678   Multiple
21-01-2018    xyz 5678   Single
```

below is what I have achieved so far by referencing SO:

```
Sub Filter_count()
Dim item As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    uniquesArray = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

        For Each item In uniquesArray
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=item

            'Do Something


        Next
```

I am able to filter by date , but unsure how to proceed further. I am okay for a totally different solution too. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a totally different solution

Assuming `date` is in A1, parse `Product` at the space and in D2 and copied down:

```
 =IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)=1,"Single","Multiple")
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, for VBA we have to double up the double quotes something like `.Range("Cell").Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)=1,""Single"",""Multiple"")"`